# Prevent Row from Overflowing Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, containers

I am attempting fit a row of widgets to a container, but it seems to overflow when i set the property of the mainaxisalignment to MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween. This causes the row (font awesome icon) to overflow the width of the container. I'm not sure how to fit the row to the width of the container. I am getting render errors when trying to wrap the row with an expanded widget.

Not sure where i am going wrong.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                //clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child:
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Hello'
                    ),
                    Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidMoneyBillAlt)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Current result:
[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, your code is just fine. I replaced the `FontAwesomeIcons` with `Icons.money` from the default Flutter assets in a Dartpad, and there is no rendering error. The issue must be with `FontAwesomeIcons`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Better answer use `FaIcon` widget Instead of `Icon` widget

```
   Row(
                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text('Hello'),
                        FaIcon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.solidMoneyBillAlt,
                          size: 50,
                        )
                      ],
                    )
```

Comment: This solution nailed it and it answered my question. I guess there is an issue in using the Icon widget with FontAwesomeIcons where it does not respect the boundaries and almost stacks on top instead. Using FaIcon solved it and it now fits within the row without overflowing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try like this

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(

                      child: Text('Hello'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      child: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.solidMoneyBillAlt,
                        // size: 30,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
```

**SAmpleCode**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                //clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(

                      child: Text('Hello'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 50,
                      child: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.solidMoneyBillAlt,
                        // size: 30,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This seems to work, but i'm curious as to how this would scale. Is there more dynamic way to do this without having to set a fixed contact width around the icon?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you. Add your icon with padding.

```
   Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text('Hello'),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.money),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the Solution- this also works great, but just for my knowledge, is there a reason why the row extends beyond the container that's wrapped around it? My thought was that it would or should expand within the parent widget, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Yes if you can used `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` there is space in between row widgets,  refer layout [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout) hope its help to you.